# WPF binding datagrid checkbox

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm newbie to WPF programming...

I want to populate DataGrid with checkbox for each unique application from a given list, where technician can select application(s) for each device of its choice, and once he/she clicks on 'submit' button...tool would create a  csv for the device which would later used for application mapping...

here is my xaml.

```
$Appname = 'App1', 'App2', 'App3'
[xml]$xaml= @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Application Deployment Staging" Height="672.607" Width="905.517">
   <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="368*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="425*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="TXTDeviceName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="81,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194"/>
        <GroupBox Name="Grpbx01" Header="Enter Device Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="33,16,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <GroupBox Name="Grpbx02" Header="Available Applications" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="456" Margin="34,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="810" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <DataGrid Name="Datagrd1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="412" Margin="9,16,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="776">
                <DataGrid.Columns>



                 </DataGrid.Columns>
             </DataGrid>
        </GroupBox>
        <Button Name="btn01" Content="Submit" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="226.4,578,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Height="27" FontWeight="Bold">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF77CAAB" Offset="0.771"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFAFA" Offset="0.003"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="btn02" Content="Cancel" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="337.4,576,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Height="27" FontWeight="Bold">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF98B1A8" Offset="0.771"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFAFA" Offset="0.003"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

# Add assemblie
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, PresentationCore, WindowsBase, System.DirectoryServices, system.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms, WindowsFormsIntegration

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{ Set-Variable -Name "$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop }

$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1

If I understand your problem correct you need to add a class like *MyApplicationList* at first. Here are an example:

```
public class MyApplicationList
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will create in your code an public property *ObservableCollection* (its a list).

```
public ObservableCollection<MyApplicationList> ItemList { get; set; }
```

Now create entries for the list and add them to the datagrid:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<MyApplicationList> ItemList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ItemList = new ObservableCollection<MyApplicationList>();
        ItemList.Add(new MyApplicationList { ApplicationName = "App 1" });
        ItemList.Add(new MyApplicationList { ApplicationName = "App 2" });
        ItemList.Add(new MyApplicationList { ApplicationName = "App 3" });

        Datagrd1.ItemsSource = ItemList;
    }
    ...
}
```

In the XAML-Code you will modify the *datagrid* to this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Datagrd1" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="9,16,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ApplicationName}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The last step would now to add an event to the *submit* button:

```
<Button Name="btn01" 
        Content="Submit" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="5,0,5,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="90" 
        Height="27" 
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Click="btn01_Click">
    <Button.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF77CAAB" Offset="0.771"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFAFA" Offset="0.003"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

In the event-handler you can check what the user has selected:

```
private void btn01_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Her you can check what the user has selectet and save in a file
    // Get the items from the ObservableCollection
}
```

This would be one way to do this as an beginner and hopefully it was understandable.

## Solution 2

If you will do it nice you implement it as *MVVM-patter*.
Then you do something like this:
Create a new class like MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyApplicationList> ItemList { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ItemList = new ObservableCollection<MyApplicationList>();
        ItemList.Add(new MyApplicationList { ApplicationName = "App 1" });
        ItemList.Add(new MyApplicationList { ApplicationName = "App 2" });
        ItemList.Add(new MyApplicationList { ApplicationName = "App 3" });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In the class of the *MainWindow* set the *MainWindowViewModel.cs* to the *DataContext* property.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

Now bind the *ObservableCollection* in the *MainWindow.xaml* to the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Datagrd1" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="9,16,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ApplicationName}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The get the events of the buttons in the class *MainWindowViewModel.cs*, add a property in code behind and bind the command to the buttons.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand SubmitButtonPress { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ...
        SubmitButtonPress = new RelayCommand(SubmitButtonPressExecute, o => true);
        ...
    }

    private void SubmitButtonPressExecute(object o)
    {
        // Her you can check what the user has selectet and save in a file
        // Get the items from the ObservableCollection
    }
}
```

Her a like for an example for the class *RelayCommand* ([C# Corner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/))
Add the command to the buttons in *MainWindow.xaml*:

```
...
<Button Name="btn01" 
        Content="Submit" 
        Command="{Binding SubmitButtonPress}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"                    
        Margin="5,0,5,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="90" 
        Height="27" 
        FontWeight="Bold">
    <Button.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF77CAAB" Offset="0.771"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFAFA" Offset="0.003"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
...
```

I hope this answer your question and helps.

Comment: Thanks @kunukiesel for prompt response, given xaml code helped me to get desired results in UI, however i'm facing issue when I want to export 'selected' application using PowerShell...I'm just getting single record/value to selected items...here is button event 
 
`
$btn01.Add_Click({
If (-NOT ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($DeviceName.Text)))  {
    $Computername  = $DeviceName.Text

            
    $Datagrd1.SelectedItems | out-file "C:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append
    

    }    
})
`

Comment: No problem and happy to hear that it works. I'm not very familiar with PowerShell. But it looks like the problem is _$Datagrd1.SelectedItems_. This will only return the selected items in the view of the _datagrid_. If you select one, you will get one, if you select two you will get tow and so on. If you like to have all items try _$Datagrd1.ItemsSource_. Then hoppefully all will save in the *.txt file. To get only the checked items try: _Datagrd1.ItemsSource.OfType<MyApplicationList>().Where(x => x.IsSelected)_ or something like this (don't know if this is possible).